# 2 Lists to Sorted Dictionary back to 2 Lists (Multiple Key Values)

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, key

I am trying to take two lists: one that contains dates and one that contains scores, then zip them into a dictionary, then sort by the key value, then turn them back in two lists (which are still sorted). The problem that I am encountering is that the dictionary does not keep multiple key values. My code is as follows:

```
date = ['2015/07/13', '2015/07/13', '2015/07/07', '2015/07/06',...] 
#there are 59 of these dates
Scores = [9.5, 13.9, 15.5, 12.9 .... ] #There are 59 of these scores
dictionary = dict(zip(date, Scores)) 
d = sorted(dictionary.items()) 
dte = []
scr = []
for i in d: 
    dte.append(i[0]) 
    scr.append(i[1])
```

However, when I print out these lists the length is only 24 in length instead of 59, which it should be. The multiple same keys are not coming back out. I was wondering if there was an easy way to get all 59 sorted elements back in two lists. I looked at some of the other python answers that were sort of similar, but none had worked for me. Ideally, I would not like to create objects for the dates (unless that is the easiest method), however when I tried to do so I kept getting errors. Also, I am on Python 2.7.

Comment: Why use a dictionary? You could use another list `[[a1,b1], [a2,b2], ...] `

Comment: FWIW, it makes sense to keep each date-score pair together, and tuples are great for that. Having them in separate lists can be dangerous, since it's so easy for the lists to get out of sync if something goes wrong.

Comment: I will keep that in mind! Thanks! I'm not manipulating the data anymore so I think everything should be good, but I will keep the data-score in a pair together if I decide to change some things up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date, Scores = zip(*sorted(zip(date, Scores)))
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. Now I just create a new list for the dates and index through x[0] and the same for x[1] and I have two ordered lists of dates with their corresponding scores! Thanks!

Comment: Code-only answers are not recommended!

Comment: @Christian - Granted, but I don't know what an explanation would add. Feel free to edit my answer if you can make it better, or steal my code and incorporate it into your own.

Comment: @Mike: Robᵩ's code returns the sorted data in tuples but you can convert a tuple to a list (if you _really_ need lists) by doing `Scores = list(Scores)`.

Comment: @PM2Ring right, I turned them back into lists from a tuple. I wanted lists because I wanted to plot some of the data I was getting. I just set x = to what Rob said and then indexed through x[0] and x[1] to get lists back

Comment: @Mike If you don't need to change the values tuples are superior to lists. And any function that can read lists can read tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries do not support multiple copies of identical keys. Your keys should be unique. One way to accomplish this is to make the key a tuple of your dates and scores unless you got the same score on the same day. In which case you could add a third list numbered 0 to 58 and use that as the third element (make it a triple instead of a tuple) as a tiebreaker when sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Working with lists in this situation might make more sense:

```
dates = ['2015/07/13', '2015/07/13', '2015/07/07', '2015/07/06'] 
scores = [9.5, 13.9, 15.5, 12.9] 

ldates_scores = zip(dates, scores)

dte = sorted(ldates_scores)
scr = sorted(ldates_scores, key=lambda x: x[1])

print dte
print scr
print

for date,score in dte:
    print "Date: %-10s   Score: %d" % (date, score)

print

for date,score in scr:
    print "Date: %-10s   Score: %d" % (date, score)
```

The output is two lists, sorted first by date (as you are using YYYY/MM/DD), and the second list sorted by score. I have kept the pairs together. The output is as follows:

```
[('2015/07/06', 12.9), ('2015/07/07', 15.5), ('2015/07/13', 9.5), ('2015/07/13', 13.9)]
[('2015/07/13', 9.5), ('2015/07/06', 12.9), ('2015/07/13', 13.9), ('2015/07/07', 15.5)]

Date: 2015/07/06   Score: 12
Date: 2015/07/07   Score: 15
Date: 2015/07/13   Score: 9
Date: 2015/07/13   Score: 13

Date: 2015/07/13   Score: 9
Date: 2015/07/06   Score: 12
Date: 2015/07/13   Score: 13
Date: 2015/07/07   Score: 15
```

Comment: Indeed, well spotted, have fixed.

Answer (score -1):

The keys in a dict will be unique so you are only capturing a single item for each date. No need for the dict...zip will return a tuple which you then sort.

```
 z = zip(date, Scores)
 sorted(z, key=lambda val: val[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: The OP is sorting by the key value, i.e. the **date** not the **Score**, so you're lambda isn't correct.