# sort list reference to another in decending order

Tags: python, list, sorting, zip

Trying to sort a list but keep the connection to another list. Did some reading and found the zip function, but I want to sort the list in descending order of age, nor name.

```
names = ["Ged","Ethan","Sam","Paul"]
ages = [15,9,12,19]
list(zip(names,ages))
for i,j in sorted(zip(names,ages),reverse=True):
  print(i,j)
```

I can't seem to get the rest of it. Any help please?

Comment: zip (ages, names) instead of (names, ages) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2 Lists to Sorted Dictionary back to 2 Lists (Multiple Key Values)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457548/2-lists-to-sorted-dictionary-back-to-2-lists-multiple-key-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add a `key` function to return reversed tuple as a criterion:

```
for i,j in sorted(zip(names,ages),reverse=True,key=lambda x : x[::-1]):
   print(i,j)
```

so age is taken in consideration first, and then the name (if same age), better than just `lambda x : x[1]` which doesn't take the name into account at all

Another easy way would be to revert the fields so natural sort criterion works:

```
for i,j in sorted(zip(ages,names),reverse=True):
   print(j,i)
```